# error in SQL syntax check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server?

Tags: java, netbeans, phpmyadmin

## I have below Update Query I cannot find an error in Query

```
 public void updateContact(contact cont){
    
     Connection con=myConnection.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps ;
    try {
        // below is Query Check full line 
   String updateQuery=" UPDATE `mycontact` SET `firstName`=?,`lastName`=?,`group`=?,`phone`=?,`email`=?,`address`=?, WHERE `id`=?";

       ps=con.prepareStatement(updateQuery);
       ps.setString(1, cont.getFirstName());
       ps.setString(2, cont.getLastName());
       ps.setString(3, cont.getGroup());
       ps.setString(4, cont.getPhone());
       ps.setString(5, cont.getEmail());
       ps.setString(6,cont.getAddress() );
       ps.setInt(7, cont.getCid());
     
       if(ps.executeUpdate() !=0){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "contact Data Edited ");
           }else{
                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Somthing Wrong");

               }       
       
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("err in  update query");
        Logger.getLogger(contactQuery.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

> Front.contactQuery updateContact
>
> SEVERE: null
>
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error
>
> in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server

Comment: You have an extra comma before "where":  `address=?, WHERE `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the comma behind the address:

```
`address`=?,
```

SQL cannot ignore an extra comma at the end. So be careful when copy-pasting to edit your SQL text.

Comment: Thanks for your help